# error when clicking on an array of sub elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make these sub elements clickable individually. When I click these subelements, I want it to read "clicked".

for reference: state = {
        list: [ { sublist: [
          "johnny", 
          "carl"]}
        ]
      }

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Comp from './Comp';

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    list: [ { sublist: [
      "johnny", 
      "carl"]}
    ]
  }

  changetext = event => {
    //const { textContent } = event.target;
    const textContent = event.target.textContent;
    // Always use the callback syntax for setState when you need to refer to the previous state

    this.setState(
      {list: this.state.list[0].sublist.map(el => textContent === el ? "clicked" : el)});
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <Comp list = {this.state.list}
        changetext = {this.changetext}/> 
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here is where I send the state that iterates and displays a list of divs. I want to make each clickable and change the text to "clicked" for each individual sub element of list.

This works fine when I set the state = {list: ["johny", "carl"]} without an inner object and another array in the object.(Also, setting {props.list[0].sublist[i]} to props.list[i]). But When I try to do the equivalent for reading the sublist, it craps out and I get the error on the bottom.

```
import React from 'react';

const Comp = props => {

    let listarr = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        listarr[i] = <div key={i} onClick={props.changetext}>{props.list[0].sublist[i]}</div>;
    }

    return(
        <div>{listarr}</div>

    );
}

export default Comp;
```

when i try to click each element I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
Comp
C:/Users/cburzo/Desktop/reactest3/src/Comp.js:12
   9 | 
  10 |    for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  11 |    {
> 12 |        listarr[i] = <div key={i} onClick={props.changetext}>{props.list[0].sublist[i]}</div>;
  13 |    }
  14 |    
  15 |    return(
View compiled
▶ 15 stack frames were collapsed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting your state wrong, map returns an array and assigns it to list which is not how your initial state was stuctured, what you want is this:

```
  this.setState({
      list: [
        {
          sublist: this.state.list[0].sublist.map(
            el => (textContent === el ? "clicked" : el)
          )
        }
      ]
    });
```

Comment: @chree Did you get it , or do you need more explaination?